# Create a dynamic 'if' statement in Excel without VBA

Tags: excel, if-statement, array-formulas

*** Updated ***

I have a rather large excel data set that I'm trying to summarise using up to 3 dimensions: region, sector, industry.
Any combination of these dimensions can be set or left blank and I need to create a formula that accommodates this **WITHOUT** using VBA.

Within the data I've set up named ranges to refer to these dimensions.

I'm using an array formula but I'd like to dynamically create a string which is then used as the boolean argument in the array formula.

For instance if:

```
A1 = "Hong Kong" (region)
B1 = <blank> (sector)
C1 = <blank> (industry)
```

I create a dynamic string in D1 such that

```
D1 = (region="Hong Kong")
```

I then want to use the string in D1 to create an array formula

```
E1 = {counta(if(D1,employees))}
```

However, if the user includes a sector such that:

```
 A2 = "Hong Kong" (region)
 B2 = "finance" (sector)
 C2 = <blank> (industry)
```

Then I want the string in D2 to update to:

```
D2 = (region="Hong Kong")*(sector="finance")
```

Which then automatically updates the value in E2 which still has the same formula.

```
E2 = {counta(if(D2,employees))}
```

Is this possible? Alternatively is there any other way of achieving the same outcome, keeping in mind that I need to be able to copy D1 and E1 down into different rows so that different combinations of the dimensions can be **viewed simultaneously**.

Thanks.

*** Updated  ***

To be clear, the reason the I need the values in column D to be dynamic is so that I can create different scenarios in Row 1, Row 2, Row 3 etc. and I need the values in column E of each row to match the criteria set in columns A:C of that row.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you probably want [DCOUNT](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/DCOUNT-function-c1fc7b93-fb0d-4d8d-97db-8d5f076eaeb1).

Comment: If you want to count the number of cells in the "Employees" column of your data table which contain numbers use `DCOUNT`. If you want to count the number of cells which are not blank (ie contain either numbers or text) use `DCOUNTA`. If you want to sum the numbers of employees meeting the criteria use `DSUM`.

Comment: Thanks @DSerg, I've never used DCount before. I've just given it a test, and it works for the first row beneath the field heading, but not for subsequent rows. Is it possible to use it down multiple rows or only for the row directly beneath the field headings?

Comment: The database functions `DSUM`, `DCOUNT` etc all work similarly. The syntax is (using `DSUM` as an example), `DSUM(database, field, criteria)`. `database` is your full data set including its header row, `field` is the field or column you want to operate on - presumably `"employees"` - and `criteria` is a table of criteria (including a header row of field names) in which items in the same row are linked by AND whilst rows are linked by OR. Excel's help might lead you to think that the criteria and database have to be in the same set of worksheet columns but actually they don't have to be.

Comment: @DMM I've just updated the question to provide some more clarity. Using the D functions, can I return more than a single set of values eg. A count when ONLY region is set and then another count on a different row when region and sector is set and then on another row another count when a different region is selected. From what I could work out from the Excel help this didn't appear possible without recreating the criteria headers for each variation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes the criteria table can have fields such as Region and Sector - suppose these headers are in cells M1 and N1. If you just want  Region as a criterion, put the value (e.g. "Hong-Kong") in M2 and leave N2 empty. If you want to set both a region and a sector put the relevant values in cells M2 and N2. In both cases you can set the criteria (ie third) argument of the database function as `M1:N2`. You could also use "industry" as a criterion (add header in O1, value in O2) and use `M1:O2` as the criteria range. This gives you the dynamic criteria functionality you appear to be seeking.

Comment: And make sure you are using the whole database table including the header row as the first argument of the function, not just the "employees" column. The database functions are not entered into the worksheet as array functions.

Comment: @DMM If the headings are in Row 1 (A1:C1), and I have a various combination of the criteria in A2:C2 and DSUM in D2, how do I set up the DSUM formula in D3 such that it doesn't include any of the criteria in row 2? That is the DSUM formulas in D2 only refer to the values in A2:C2, D3 are only dependant on A3:C3, D4 on A4:C4 etc.
My understand of the database formulas is the a sum in D3 will include values A2:C3, which doesn't work in my case. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot put different criteria into successive rows of a criteria table and have a database function generate a result for each row. Multiple rows can be used but the criteria they represent are combined using OR. Generating separate results for different criteria requires the different criteria to be specified in different criteria tables.

Answer (score 0):

There had to be a fairly simple way!

[image: Screen shot of solution]

Columns `B:D` contain the criteria, `A` is a criterion number and `E` is the result of applying the `DSUM` function to the criterion in that row. I've used `DSUM` as it seems more natural (to me at least) to sum employee numbers. However, DCOUNT can equally well be used. For brevity I've not shown the data I'm using but it is a very trivial data set with just a few rows of test data.

The first set of criteria in row 2 is: Sector takes value of "Man" (manufacturing) whilst Region and Industry are unspecified. The 3rd set of criteria (in row 4) is: the Region is "Fr" (for France) AND the Industry is "Cars". The results in the `DSUM` column are obtained by applying the set of criteria in the corresponding row. All, some or even none of the cells in a row may contain entries.

The approach used is based on columns `G:J`, where with the exception cells `G1` and `G2` (which contain the numbers 0 and 1, respectively) everything in these columns has been generated by a formula.

There are twice as many rows in columns `G:J` as there are sets of criteria listed in `B:D` and the rows should be taken in pairs. The first pair (rows 1 and 2) provide a criterion table for use in `DSUM` corresponding to the first set of criteria (the table is cells `H1:J2`), the second pair in rows 3 and 4 provides a criterion table for the second set of criteria (cells `H3:J4`), etc. (Ignore the 11th row - I copied too many rows downwards in the screenshot!)

Column `G` has a fairly obvious pattern and can be generated by applying a simple `=IF()` function in cell `G3` which references the starting pair in `G1` and `G2` with the formula in `G3` then copied downwards.

The cells in columns `H:J` reference the appropriate cells of the set of all criteria (`B1:D6` in the screenshot) using the `INDEX` function (and making use of the value in column `G`along the way). It is not too difficult to create a single formula that can be copied from `H1` to the range `H1:J11` by judicious use of mixed relative and absolute addressing and an `IF` or two). Note that references to an empty cell in `B2:D6` will generate a value of 0 in the corresponding cell in `H:J` so the construct `IF(x=0,"",x)` must be used - this makes the formula used in the cells in columns `H:J` a bit clunky but not excessively so.

Having generated the 5 criteria tables corresponding to the 5 sets of criteria in `B:D`, use is made of the `OFFSET` function to deliver the correct criterion table as the third argument of the `DSUM` functions in column `E`.

I chose to base my `OFFSET`s on cell `$H$1`, so the top-left cell of the criterion table for the first set of criteria is offset from my base cell by 0 rows and 0 columns. The second criterion table is offset by 2 rows and 0 columns, the third by 4 rows and 0 columns. It should be clear how the number of offset rows and columns to use can be calculated from the corresponding criterion number in column A. It should also be obvious that the final two arguments of the OFFSET function will always be 2 and 3. So my `DSUM()` functions in column `E` look something like

`=DSUM(myData,"Employees",OFFSET($H$1,row_offset,0,2,3))`

where `myData` is the named range containing the test dataset and `row_offset` is a very simple formula involving the corresponding value in column `A`.

It would have been nice to have been able to deliver the third argument of the function without having to adopt the approach of effectively reproducing the sets of criteria in B1:D6 in cells H1:J10. Whilst there are ways to generate the required criterion table arrays formulaically without putting them onto the worksheet, I found that `DSUM` generated an error when applying such an array as its third argument.