# Ignore blank parameters in Excel array formula

Tags: arrays, excel, array-formulas

I'm using an array formula to return sums and counts on a large data set.

The array formula can have up to 3 arguments but the formula needs to accommodate when any or all of the arguments are `<blank>`, **WITHOUT using VBA**.

For example

```
A1 = "Australia"
B1 = "Finance"
C1 = "Female"
```

D1 contains the formula

```
D1 = {count(if((region=A1)*(sector=B1)*(gender=C1),population))}
```

Sometimes one of the criteria will be blank

```
 A1 = "Australia"
 B1 = <blank>
 C1 = "Male"
```

In this case I'd like the formula to return the equivalent of:

```
D1 = {count(if((region=A1)*(gender=C1),population))}
```

In the extreme case A1, B1 and C1 could be all blank in which case the formula in `D1` should return the equivalent of `Count(population)`

Is there a way to create an array formula that accounts for these possibilities? I originally tried to create a dynamic argument string

```
E1 = "(region=A1)*(sector=B1)*(gender=C1)"
```

and then use the string as the argument within the array formula

```
D1 = {count(if(E1,population))}
```

but I could find a way to get this to work.

I've tried a number of solutions, but there is always a key element missing. By using `isblank` I can determine if the cell is blank, but in order for this to be useful I'd need to turn this returned value into an array of boolean values of length `count(population)`.

Any and all ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Nz() ? Encapsulate your current code with that and give it a try. I've had issues with blanks/nulls here and there myself.

Another option could be the IIF() statement. But that might not do what you want it to. Here are reference links:

Nz: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php

IIF: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php

Comment: PS - you can use both of these in controls, without having to open up a VBA module.

Comment: Pretty sure OP is using Excel, not Access and neither of these formulas are valid Excel formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need *VBA* and you also don't even need an *array formula*.  You can use **SUMPRODUCT()** with *wildcards*.

Say we have:

[image]

In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(A1="","*",A1)
```

and copy across.  This will display either an asterisk or the value above.

Then use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,G1:G10,1))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,H1:H10,1))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2,I1:I10,1)))
```

This is a way to get **SUMPRODUCT()** to accept the asterisk as a wildcard:

[image]

Comment: that appears to be a far more elegant solution than what I finally came up with. I'll have to play with it some more as I haven't quite worked out how it works and I'm wondering if it will work on numeric values. If column J was numeric and I wanted to perform SUM, AVERAGE, MAX and MIN on these based on the values in G, H and I would that work?
This is what I eventually came up with:
=SUM(IF(IF(ISBLANK($A3),region<>"x",region=$A3)*IF(ISBLANK($C3),sector<>"x",sector=$C3)*IF(ISBLANK($D3),gender<>"x",gender=$D3),population))
where "x" is a dummy variable to return at 'TRUE' values

Comment: You **may** be able to get this type of functionality using *AutoFilter* and analyze the results with the **SUBTOTAL()** function.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159748/create-a-dynamic-if-statement-in-excel-without-vba which appears to the same question asked a few hours earlier.